# How to instance a codesample of tinymce version 4x?

Tags: tinymce

I really like tinymce version 4x, but when i'm trying to use it, i have a problem, when i  use codesample it work perfectly in tinymce editor, but i i want to show it in tag , it's my trouble.Please tell me if you have any ideas.
Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE - TinyMCE 4.3.2 eliminates the `<br>` tags that this post shows how to remove so Step 3 should not be needed in 4.3.2 or later.**

The key to resolving this is knowing that TinyMCE relies on Prism.js for the syntax highlighting capability.

If you want to extract the content from TinyMCE and have it appear elsewhere you need to...

Step 1: Include `Prism.js` and `prism.css` in your page - these can be downloaded from the Prism web site.

Step 2: Use TinyMCE's APIs to extract the content from the editor.  For example:

```
var htmlToLoad = tinyMCE.get('area3').getContent();
```

Step 3: Replace any `<br />` elements in the content with a simple newline:

```
var htmlToLoad = tinyMCE.get('area3').getContent();
htmlToLoad = htmlToLoad.replace(/<br \/>/g,'\n');
```

You need to do this because Prism's highlight function (see Step 5) will remove the `<br />` tags causing the spacing to not look as things do in TinyMCE.

Step 4: Place the content into an HTML block element:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = htmlToLoad;
```

Step 5: Run Prism's highlight function

```
Prism.highlightAll();
```

This triggers Prism to re-evaluate the DOM for things that it should highlight - it won't do this automatically.

Comment: Thank for help @Michea Fromin, i have a question how to use Tiny API's ? and how to do it?